# Events the building block of spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime

In general relativity, events are the basic building block of Spacetime. Quoting Robert Geroch,

> "The collection of all possible events--those which have happened, are happening,
> or ever will happen----will be denoted by $M$, and called spacetime" (See page 9: https://uchicago.app.box.com/s/x4fi21zy1xnvja2j32vzlnjp7wo9802m).

So my death is already there in spacetime (I have come to know this view is called the Block universe theory); now my question is whether Spacetime contains all the possible ways I will die (say on my bed or in a car crash and so on) or it only contains **the** event (let say my death in a hospital) that my world line will end at some point in the future?

Comment: It only contains the way you *will* die, there is no splitting off into different possible futures in GR.

Answer (score 1):

Geroch uses the word event to mean a point in space and time- ie having no spatial or temporal extent. He uses the term spacetime to mean the container, if you like, of all possible points. His notion of an event is more abstract than your idea of your death, and he certainly does not imply that all of your possible deaths exist somehow in spacetime.